ng xi18n --i18n-format=xlf throw module not found error
when I try to ng xi18n --i18n-format=xlf
I get an error. When I run to app with ng serve there are no problem
It is an angular-cli 1.4.2
 30% building modules 167/184 modules 17 active ...t/create-support-tekst.component.scssChild compilation failed:
Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/src/app/assets/frontpage/css/app.css' in '/Users//WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend':
Error: Can't resolve '/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/src/app/assets/frontpage/css/app.css' in '/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend'
Error: Child compilation failed:
Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/src/app/assets/frontpage/css/app.css' in '/Users//WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend':
Error: Can't resolve '/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/src/app/assets/frontpage/css/app.css' in '/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend'
    at childCompiler.compile (/Users//WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/resource_loader.js:78:28)
    at applyPluginsAsync.err (/Users//WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:510:14)
    at next (/Users//WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at compilation.seal.err (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:507:11)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:195:46)
    at applyPluginsAsync.err (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:677:19)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:195:46)
    at applyPluginsAsync.err (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:668:11)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:195:46)
    at applyPluginsAsync.err (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:663:10)
    at next (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
    at Compilation.compilation.plugin (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/resource_loader.js:66:21)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/WebstormProjects/driiver-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:659:9)

I try to run  ng xi18n --i18n-format=xlf file  to create a xlf file and it throws an error
